# NullPointerException when using SecurityEntityFilteringFeature with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

Upgraded to **Jersey 2.16** and trying the new feature that supports **role-based entity filtering via Jackson**.

`NullPointerException` is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.ObjectGraphImpl.getSubgraphs(ObjectGraphImpl.java:109)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.JacksonObjectProvider.createSubfilters(JacksonObjectProvider.java:89)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.JacksonObjectProvider.transform(JacksonObjectProvider.java:74)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.JacksonObjectProvider.transform(JacksonObjectProvider.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.AbstractObjectProvider.createFilteringObject(AbstractObjectProvider.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.AbstractObjectProvider.getFilteringObject(AbstractObjectProvider.java:100)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.spi.AbstractObjectProvider.getFilteringObject(AbstractObjectProvider.java:83)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.writeTo(FilteringJacksonJaxbJsonProvider.java:130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:106)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.spi.ContentEncoder.aroundWriteTo(ContentEncoder.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.spi.ContentEncoder.aroundWriteTo(ContentEncoder.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:86)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1118)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:662)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:418)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:408)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:306)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

if I use a Jackson entity inherited from an abstract class, having an abstract method that returs another object of some custom class.

`JacksonFeature` and `SecurityEntityFilteringFeature` is registered and resource method looks like:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RolesAllowed(ACTUAL_ROLE)
public User getTestData() {
  return new User("name", "address");
}
```

where User is defined as:

```
public class User extends SuperUser {

  private String name;
  private String address;

  public User(String name, String address){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  @Override
  public MoreData getMoreData() {
    return null;
  }
}

abstract class SuperUser {
    public abstract MoreData getMoreData();
}

class MoreData {
}
```

Everything works fine If `getMoreData()` returns a non-custom objection for instance `String`.

Any idea if this is a bug in roles based entity filtering feature via Jackson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised this as a bug on Jira and it is now fixed in version 2.18

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2824